# remove record from results on click

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, onclick, display

I have a question that, I would have thought has definitely been asked before so excuse me if I am phrasing it wrong but I was unable to find it. The question requires a few separate snippets of code to address. I have an application that we use to review the validity of leads submitted to our client from certain forms for billing purposes. What I am wanting, is for when the user presses the button "valid" or "invalid", it assigns the lead the proper status and removes it from the currently displayed table, which would be leads that 'need review'. These leads have a needsreview value of 'null', which is defaulted. The other leads are assigned an appropriate value of 1 or 0 upon the button press.

That all works, the only thing I cannot figure out is how to not redirect the user to restart the search on click. I just want it to remove the record from what is currently displayed. Here is a few pieces of the code, I would greatly appreciate any help. Again, it all works, just in not the most convenient way and I am not sure how to do it the better way, I just need someone more experienced to point me in the right direction.

Here is the buttons code:

```
          <td style="background:#fff;border:none;">
          <button  style="margin-bottom:2.5%;margin-top:2.5%;background:#2ECC71;border-radius:5px;width:175px;height:30px;border:3px solid #3FC380;color:#fff;font-weight:bold;" onclick="location='admin.php?action=validCustomer&amp;customersId=<?php echo $customers->id?>'">Valid</button>
      </td>
      <td style="background:#fff;border:none;">
            <button  style="margin-bottom:2.5%;margin-top:2.5%;background:#2ECC71;border-radius:5px;width:175px;height:30px;border:3px solid #3FC380;color:#fff;font-weight:bold;" onclick="location='admin.php?action=invalidCustomer&amp;customersId=<?php echo $customers->id?>'">Not Valid</button>
      </td>
```

Here is the other relevant code:

```
function searchIsValid() {
$results['formAction'] = "searchIsValid";
$results['pageTitle'] = "Search By Validation Status";
require (TEMPLATE_PATH . "/admin/searchIsValid.php" );
}
function validCustomer(){
if (!$customers = customers::getById( (int)$_GET['customersId'] ) ){
    echo "Error getting customer ID";
}
$results['formAction'] = "validCustomer";
$results['pageTitle'] = "Lead Validated";
$customers->validCustomer($_SESSION['username']);
header( "Location: admin.php?action=searchIsValid" );
}
function invalidCustomer(){
if (!$customers = customers::getById( (int)$_GET['customersId'] ) ){
    echo "Error getting customer ID";
}
$results['formAction'] = "invalidCustomer";
$results['pageTitle'] = "Lead Invalidated";
$customers->invalidCustomer($_SESSION['username']);
header( "Location: admin.php?action=searchIsValid" );
}
```

And finally, the last piece of relevant code, the SQL part:

```
public function update() {

// Does the customer object have an ID?
if ( is_null( $this->id ) ) trigger_error ( "customers::update(): Attempt to update a customer object that does not have its ID property set.", E_USER_ERROR      );

// Update the customer
$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
$sql = "UPDATE leads SET valid=:valid WHERE id = :id";
$st = $conn->prepare ( $sql );
$st->bindValue( ":id", $this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT );
$st->execute();
$conn = null;
}

public function validCustomer($username) {

// Does the customer object have an ID?
if ( is_null( $this->id ) ) trigger_error ( "customers::update(): Attempt to update a customer object that does not have its ID property set.", E_USER_ERROR );



 // Update the customer
    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    // if invalid
     $sql = "UPDATE leads SET valid=1, reviewedby='$username' WHERE id = :id";
        $st = $conn->prepare ( $sql );
        $st->bindValue( ":id", $this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT );
        $st->execute();
        $conn = null;
     }
     public function invalidCustomer($username) {

    // Does the customer object have an ID?
    if ( is_null( $this->id ) ) trigger_error ( "customers::update(): Attempt to update a customer object that does not have its ID property set.", E_USER_ERROR );

    // Update the customer
    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    // if invalid
     $sql = "UPDATE leads SET valid=0, reviewedby='$username' WHERE id = :id";
        $st = $conn->prepare ( $sql );
        $st->bindValue( ":id", $this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT );
        $st->execute();
        $conn = null;
    }
```

I think this is all the relevant code but, I probably forgot some so feel free to remind me, and thanks again for taking the time to read my post and offer assistance!

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'm not super familiar with AJAX, did you mean that it is impossible to do with PHP? Thanks for responding. @MarkVincentManjac

Comment: well, PHP is a server-side script so every changes you make will only take effect after the page is refresh so using AJAX would call the server-side script on runtime.

Comment: @MarkVincentManjac I was wondering if somehow I could give the specific TR display:none on the onclick function? Is that a possible thing? I figured probably not because the rows don't have a specific ID, they call and ID from the database. Thanks for your time by the way.

Comment: Why would you do that if you just want to have a new set of records displayed base on the search criteria given by the user? You already filter the records so some of the records that's not in the user search criteria should not be shown already. But ofcourse it will only take effect after the page refresh.

Comment: @MarkVincentManjac Well, mainly because the records don't come in rapidly enough to where by the time the user presses valid or invalid on each there will be new responses to their query, it's done basically monthly. So, as long as it removed the record from the currently displayed list, and did what it already does assigning the value to the database it would be fine. I agree that your way is probably better I just don't really know AJAX at all so I think it would be hard for me to implement. However, if that's the only way I will research to the documentation. Thank you for helping :)

Comment: Like I said , AJAX will call the server-side script without even redirecting or refreshing the page and also it will renew the results without refreshing the page. You want to not redirect the user so using AJAX is the best option you have. AJAX is not that complicated and I bet you can learn jQuery in less than a week base on how much time you put on studying it.

Comment: @MarkVincentManjac sounds like AJAX is the way to go then. Thank you Mark! I can't find where to mark your answer as correct but I will mark it when I do.

Comment: I didn't post an answer so you can just upvote my comment.